# Uploadify - get source image path

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I use last flash version version of uploadify. I need to take source image path, from user computer in process of upload, or after upload.

How to do that?

Comment: Generally not possible for security reasons, not even in Flash anymore I think

Comment: If you're trying to do this, I'd say you're going down the wrong path. The web server and web application have no business knowing anything about the client file system.

Comment: Well, there *are* a few legit exceptions - for example, a document management system where the document's original upload location is relevant info to be stored. There are not many exceptions like that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok its easy!
Consider the following HTML as example.

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />

<img src='' id='myimg' />
```

you can add onSelect event when initializing and from it you can add source to any img element

```
$(function() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
    'swf'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'onSelect' : function(file) {
        $("#myimg").attr('src',file.name);
    }
    });
});
```

This will update imgae source and your problem will be resolved.